# Selenium and Python Error: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to find the destination input box on the Google Flights page using Selenium. The box itself doesn't have any useful identifiers (unless selenium can us jsname to find elements). Right now I'm using a locator to make selenium choose between two c-wiz boxes and I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

I guess I'm not exactly sure how to use a relative locator? My ultimate goal is to get Selenium to send the text "JFK" to the destination input box on https://www.google.com/travel/flights so if anyone has a more elegant approach I'm all ears :)

Here's my code for reference:

```
bigWiz = bigBody.find_elements(wizLoc)"
```

is throwing the error:

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with

driver_service = Service(executable_path = '/path/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.google.com/travel/flights'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service = driver_service)
browser.get(url)
bigBody = browser.find_element(By.ID,'yDmH0d')
wrongWiz = bigBody.find_element(By.ID, 'ow4')
wizLoc = browser.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, 'c-wiz').below(wrongWiz))
bigWiz = bigBody.find_elements(wizLoc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination input box on the [Google Flights page](https://www.google.com/travel/flights) is a dynamic element.

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/travel/flights')
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Enter your destination']//preceding-sibling::div[1]//input").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Enter your destination']//preceding-sibling::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("JFK")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: GoogleFlightsDestination]

Comment: Amazing! This is a great fix. I was able to use the xpath and preceeding-sibling format to select departure input box as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `jsname` in a locator, e.g. a CSS selector would be `input[jsname='yrriRe']`. The problem is that it finds 8 elements on the page so it's not useful in this case.

You can do this a couple ways.

**Active element**

When the page first loads, the cursor is actually in the element you want so you can use simply

```
driver.switch_to.active_element.click()
driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys("DFW")
```

NOTE: The active element changes after the click so you have to refetch it in the second line.

**CSS selector**

You can also use CSS selectors to find it.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-placeholder='Where to?'] input"))).send_keys("DFW")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Enter your destination'] input"))).send_keys("DFW")
```

NOTE: You should always prefer CSS selectors over XPaths because they are better supported, faster, and most times easier to read because the syntax is simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much for this note. I just rewrote my code with CSS Selectors. Much cleaner and easier!

Comment: @Fox You are welcome. There's a place for XPaths because there are things that can only be done with XPaths like complicated DOM traversal and locating elements by contained text but other than that, everything should be 1. ID, 2. CSS selector, and then a distant 3. XPath.